# Kibana visualize, count the length of the array

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I got the documents like this
[image]

TradeInfoList contains 3 records.

The question is how to count this in the visualize module.

Like I got two documents, one of them got 2 Trade Info, another one got 3 Trade Info, I want to sum them and show 5 in the visualize. How can I do that, I have try scripted fields, seem not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create a metric panel, then choose sum as aggregation. After that select `TradeInfoList` as the field, on the end you write down script in advance -> JSON input

```json
{
  "script": "return doc['TradeInfoList'].value"
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have used the script and finished the work. I have done something like if(field exist) return 1 else return 0